# What is the new syntax for UIControlStateEvents in xcode 7?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, xcode7

After updating to xcode 7, I keep getting multiple errors for a lot of code that used to work before. I get that the syntax has changed but i havent been having much luck in locating the newer updated syntaxes. Could someone tell me what I should change for the following:

```
but.addTarget(self, action: "toTrack", forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

UIControlEventTouchUpInside is an unresolved identifier in the above, as well as UIControlEventTouchDragInside in another code snippet i used. What have all these UIControlStateEvents changed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside` and `UIControlEvent.TouchDragInside`

Answer (score 0):

> What is the new syntax for UIControlStateEvents in xcode 7?

There is no new syntax for UIControlStateEvents in Xcode 7. It is exactly the same as in Xcode 6. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is an unresolved identifier Xcode 7 and Swift 2, and it was an unresolved identifier in Xcode 6 and Swift 1.